# How can I use the dropdownlist to populate/enter data?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, data-access, data-binding

Here's my existing code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="dsEmployees" DataTextField="Last_First" 
            DataValueField="EmpNum" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How can I use the existing ddl to populate new data?

Comment: @Yonita: It would be helpful if you fleshed out the question a bit more.

Comment: Is there a way to populate the NEW item from dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yonita, you need some more moving parts.  You need a datasource to bind to, for instance.

Have a look at the Data Access tutorials on the ASP.NET website:

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/

Answer (score 1):

DropDownLists end up being rendered as `<select>` tags in HTML.  These do not allow for data entry of new values.  If you're looking for something similar to a ComboBox (a textbox and a listbox combined into the same control) then you'll need to find a third-party javascript implementation that is acceptable to you; there is no control which provides that functionality in HTML or the .net framework.

Comment: Thank you Ken.
I just thought there's a way to build a dynamic dropdown list with ASP.  Thanks for the input.  :)